# Outlook 2011 rule to forward spam to abuse email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

Is there a way to create a rule that will forward an email to an abuse account (e.g. abuse@microsoft.com) if it is flagged 'Mark as Junk'?

Unfortunately, the Message Flag filter doesn't have a 'spam' or 'junk' option.

Can a rule be associated with a particular folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to create an AppleScript to do the hard work: https://github.com/craibuc/outlook-junk-email

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule that will process any email ( wildcard ) in a specific folder and forward an email to a specific address then delete the email.

A sample rule would be

> Apply this rule after the message arrives flagged for Do Not Forward
>   forward it to ...@abuse.com and delete it

An easy way would be to look for specific words contained in the body or subject and tell your anti-spam software to flag spam with those specific words.

You could also just setup a rule for a certain folder.

Comment: is this just a matter of selecting the desired folder, then creating the rule? I didn't notice a way of selecting a folder in the Rule UI.